# How to capture webform data from a WebView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview

I'm building a Mac OS native application that uses a WebView to display custom data forms. The user will be able to fill out these forms to input data to the application. I need to be able to capture whatever data gets submitted as part of these html forms.

So if for example a webform comes up that has a text field which the user can use to enter a name - along with an 'OK' button next to it which submits the data - I would need to be able to capture whatever the user entered in that text field.

Keep in mind the HTML is loaded locally, not from a URL. Like so:
[[webview mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlSource baseURL:nil];

How can I capture any data that is being send entered this way?

Comment: Could you put some example to show what you have tried, as this question is a bit broad in scope?

Comment: Do you have access to jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be done in javascript, by intercepting the `submit` of your form and tracking the data. For this answer, I assume your webpage uses jQuery:

```
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@" \
 $('#yourForm').on('submit', function(e){ \
     console.log(JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()));\
 });"];
```

If you need this information in the Objective-C code, [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html) describes how to bridge calls between javascript and Obj-C

Comment: Yes, something like this is just what I'm looking for.

However this isn't quite right. You're using a UIWebView here, it seems this is an iOS solution. I'm working strictly in MacOS for a native Mac application, not iOS. I'm using the WebView object specifically. (Not UIWebView)

Comment: Woops, sorry I missed that. I imagine the idea is portable to a MacOS application though, since it's a javascript-based implementation